# elasticsearch aggs not working on some fields

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

Mapping

```
{
   "products":{
      "mappings":{
         "product":{
            "dynamic":"strict",
            "properties":{
               "CompanyId":{
                  "type":"integer"
               },
               "CompanyName":{
                  "type":"text",
                  "fields":{
                     "raw":{
                        "type":"keyword"
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

This works

```
{
       "query":{
          "match_all":{}
       },
       "size":20,
       "aggs":{
          "CompanyId":{
             "terms":{
                "field":"CompanyId",
                "size":20,
                "order":{
                   "_count":"desc"
                }
             }
          }
       }
    }
```

But this does not (`buckets` array is empty)

```
{
   "query":{
      "match_all":{}
   },
   "size":20,
   "aggs":{
      "CompanyName.raw":{
         "terms":{
            "field":"CompanyName.raw",
            "size":20,
            "order":{
               "_count":"desc"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Why?

This is to get rid of the "mostly code" error.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse nec elementum sapien, at sollicitudin lacus. Vestibulum sit amet lectus odio. Pellentesque eu tempor elit. Aenean tempor consequat sem, nec rutrum orci euismod ut. Donec blandit malesuada sagittis. Nam pharetra porttitor diam. Mauris lobortis metus a auctor ornare. Suspendisse nec bibendum mauris. Sed efficitur purus mauris, vitae euismod purus volutpat id. Vivamus eget turpis placerat, hendrerit odio non, euismod leo. Curabitur ornare consectetur imperdiet. Proin auctor sagittis libero sit amet euismod. Nam euismod vitae est ut mollis. Fusce eget est orci. Mauris in urna sem. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae;

Comment: I used `PUT` to add `CompanyName.raw`. Do I need to get ElasticSearch to update something somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Since the mapping was changed the index needs to be rebuilt.

`POST products/_update_by_query?conflicts=proceed`